# Converting each element of a list to tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

to convert each element of list to tuple like following :

```
l = ['abc','xyz','test']
```

convert to tuple list:

```
newl = [('abc',),('xyz',),('test',)]
```

Actually I have dict with keys like this so for searching purpose I need to have these.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> l = ['abc','xyz','test']
>>> [(x,) for x in l]
[('abc',), ('xyz',), ('test',)]
>>>
```

---

Or, if you are on Python 2.x, you could just use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> # Python 2.x interpreter
>>> l = ['abc','xyz','test']
>>> zip(l)
[('abc',), ('xyz',), ('test',)]
>>>
```

---

However, the previous solution will not work in Python 3.x because `zip` now returns a zip object.  Instead, you would need to explicitly make the results a list by placing them in [`list`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#list):

```
>>> # Python 3.x interpreter
>>> l = ['abc','xyz','test']
>>> zip(l)
<zip object at 0x020A3170>
>>> list(zip(l))
[('abc',), ('xyz',), ('test',)]
>>>
```

I personally prefer the list comprehension over this last solution though.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
newl = [(i, ) for i in l]
```