# Returning a value from a python for loop function

Tags: python

I have edited my question. The code contains an is_prime formula which indicates whether a number is prime> I'm trying to extract all the prime values in the range 3 to 65

```
a = []
b = []                                             
c = []                                             
d = []
def ll_prime(n_start, n_end):  
    for number in range(n_start, n_end):
        if is_prime(number) ==True:
            a.append(number)
            b.append(1)
        else:
            c.append(number)
            d.append(0)
    return (list(zip(a,b)))
```

The above code runs fine but when I call the function ll_prime(3,65) it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-498-1a1a58988fa7> in <module>()
----> 1 ll_prime(3,65)
      2 #type(tyl)
      3 #list_values = [ v for v in tyl.values()]

<ipython-input-497-d99272d4b655> in ll_prime(n_start, n_end)
     11             c.append(number)
     12             d.append(0)
---> 13     return (list(zip(a,b)))

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Can anyone guide me as why I'm getting this error? I have searched previous question on stackoverflow but none were helpful in my case.

I want result as : [(3,1),(5,1),(7,1)] etc

Comment: you’re returning the value of your first iteration, move the return statement outside the loop

Comment: **NameError** in your script. Unless you want to fix that for you. please provide a correct [mcve] that replicates your problem. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting each element of a list to tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256366/converting-each-element-of-a-list-to-tuple)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension:

```py
def l1_prime():
    return [(i, 1) for i in mb]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) from `itertools` and zip this with your list.

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> mb = [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61]
>>> zip(mb, repeat(1))
[(3, 1), (5, 1), (7, 1), (11, 1), (13, 1), (17, 1), (19, 1), (23, 1), (29, 1), (31, 1), (37, 1), (41, 1), (43, 1), (47, 1), (53, 1), (59, 1), (61, 1)]
```

Or you can use a list comprehension like this:

```
>>> [(x, 1) for x in mb]
[(3, 1), (5, 1), (7, 1), (11, 1), (13, 1), (17, 1), (19, 1), (23, 1), (29, 1), (31, 1), (37, 1), (41, 1), (43, 1), (47, 1), (53, 1), (59, 1), (61, 1)]
```

---

**To your solution:** In your solution you return your result after the first loop iteration. So it doesn't have the right values yet. Try to move the return outside of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that your `return` command is inside your for loop, so it will only execute once. That could be why you aren't getting what you want. When I ran your code, it returned (3,1), which was only the first set of items. That makes sense if it is only running through the for loop once and then returning. Try this:

```
 mb = [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61]
list1 = []
list2 = []                                             
def prime():
    for i in mb:
        list1.append(i)
        list2.append(1)
        print(str(len(list1)))
        print(str(len(list2)))
    return (list(zip(list1,list2)))
```

When I run that, I get the correct answer